# angular css table cell multiple icon and material label on the same line

Tags: css, angular

I have an angular table grid with ng-template which contains tr elements.
I started adding several icon and everything is lining up on the same line in the table cell. However, when I added a matBadge (Material), it shows up on the next line. I tried using display:inline as my css styling but that did not work.

Here is my code so far

```
<td align="center"  >
                <i  class="fas fa-check fa-lg" ></i>
                <i   color:red;" class="fas fa-exclamation fa-lg"></i>
                <i  class="fa fa fa-fw fa-file-dollar fa-lg"></i>


                <p><span  matBadge={{5}} matBadgeOverlap="false"> </span></p>
            </td>
```

Thanks.

Comment: A paragraph tag is a block element. Remove the `<p>` that you're wrapping around it.